# Как проще организовать перерисовку окна при длительном процессе?

Tags: mfc, многопоточность, c++, visual-studio

Visual C++ 6.0 диалог на базе MFC AppWizard(exe).

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов - это посылать сообщения из потока в главное окно, а в обработчиках сообщений обновлять какую-либо информацию в окне. Пример:

```
static UINT CSomeClass::UpdaterProc(LPVOID context);

UINT CSomeClass::UpdaterProc(LPVOID context)
{
    const HWND handle = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(context);
    ASSERT(handle != NULL);

    // Послать сообщение из потока
    ::PostMessage(handle, WM_USER, ...);

    return 0;
}
```

и

```
void CSomeClass::OnCreateUpdaterThread()
{
    // Создать поток и передать хэндл
    AfxBeginThread(UpdaterProc, m_hWnd);
}

LRESULT CSomeClass::OnUser(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // Обработать сообщение     
    return 0;
}
```